# Allocating more than 4 gigs of RAM to a VM causes the VM to not start

Tags: virtualization, kvm, libvirt

I'm currently using a combination of qemu-kvm, libvirtd, and virt-manager to host some virtual RHEL 6 machines.  When I go ahead and attempt to bump the ram usage up above 4gb, the machines fail to start. What would even be the cause of this? Any information is helpful.

I'm running a 10 core, 3GHz Xeon processor, with 64 GB of ram.

Comment: Is the OS running an x86 instructions and not x86-64?  Also, this probably belongs on serverfault.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Looks like it's x86-64.  Let me take a look on serverfault